# J code block in org-mode returns ```Wrong type argument: listp, none```

Tags: emacs, org-mode, j

Following some pages on the internet I have added the following code to my init file:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((C . t)
   (J . t)
   (emacs-lisp . t)
   ))
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)
(setq org-src-lang-modes (quote (("J" . j))))
```

However, when I go into an org-file and try to eval a J block, like:

```
#+begin_src J
1 + 3
#+end_src
```

Emacs gives the following error:

`Wrong type argument: listp, "none"`

As I can see, somewhere a list was supposed to be sent but none is sent. Org version is 8.2.7. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed this issue. Apparently the interface was changed from a
parameter being a list to a cons cell.

Comment: This will sound very stupid, but what should I update? The ob-J.el file?

Comment: do `make up2` if you use org from git, or just wait for it to update in MELPA.